# Has the word individual 'outcompeted' that of person historically?

Tags: meaning, etymology, differences, vocabulary, historical-change

Would it be correct to say that the word individual have 'outcompeted' that of person since 17th century in everyday English, as well as in social sciences?

According to etymonline.com's entry on individual "Meaning "a single human being" (as opposed to a group, etc.) is from 1640s. Colloquial sense of "person" is attested from 1742. Latin individuum as a noun meant "an atom, indivisible particle," ....

As of person "c. 1200, persoun, "an individual, a human being," from Old French persone "human being, anyone, person".

If so, it would be interesting to observe how a language can change via vocabulary in parallel with a radical change experienced by a country ideologically and structurally. In this case, the change experienced by England since 17th century that has given birth to the 'modern times' with its individualism would be accountable for the change in English. Consider that originally individual indicated separateness and indivisibility which was intimately close to the era of flourishing individualism so that these properties have been projected towards a human person, and thus you get an 'individual' instead of a 'person.'

It,too, has been interesting to observe on Quorra.com that today, few anglophone people recognize the difference in the meanings of the words.

On my account, social sciences' vocabulary, too, show their sympathy for 'individual' rather than 'person.'

To avoid misinterpretation, I would add that I mean the two words as alternative words pertaining to the same object, a numerically distinct human being, which yet have different historical-and-cultural connotations one perhaps can allocate to the different kinds of society, respectively.